# What is the [reason-why] tag used for?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

A recent question used the [reason-why](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reason-why) tag for what was really an etymology question, so I retagged it appropriately. (Or at least I *think* it was appropriate.) Now I'm wondering what the tag is even *for*. It currently has no usage guidance.

It's got 25 questions under it, of which the five oldest are about the construction "*reason why*" itself.

Then, there a few other questions under that tag that are rather etymological in nature ([Why is it specifically a "rainy day" (rather than some other metaphor) when you need extra money?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/522110/why-is-it-specifically-a-rainy-day-rather-than-some-other-metaphor-when-you) and [Why do we refer to car manufacturer as 'Make'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/188032/why-do-we-refer-to-car-manufacturer-as-make)).

Some of the other questions there ask for explanations of linguistic/dialectal phenomena.

The rest of them seem to be random taggings.

I'd like to know:

- What should we be using this tag for?
- What should its wiki say?
- Should it be used in conjunction with [etymology](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology)/[phrase-origin](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase-origin)?

---

I have two questions that I think could go under that tag, but I'm waiting to see what the community thinks about the tag's use:

- [Where does the subcontinental usage of 'one' to mean 'named' come from?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/603016/where-does-the-subcontinental-usage-of-one-to-mean-named-come-from)
- [Why do we order our adjectives in certain ways: "big, blue house" rather than "blue, big house"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/599423/why-do-we-order-our-adjectives-in-certain-ways-big-blue-house-rather-than-b)

Are these and their ilk to be tagged under [reason-why](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reason-why)?

Comment: Is it useful to group questions on ELU by whether they are asking for "a reason why" versus asking for something else?

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what -any- tag is for, if all it does is repeat some keywords that should already be in the question (eg 'why'). That said, 'reason-why' for questions asking about why a certain phenomenon occurs doesn't seem any more unreasonable than most tags.

Comment: My rule of thumb is that a tag should be something I would use alone or in conjunction with other tags to try to find a potential duplicate or related question. It can be difficult to identify relevant content just by doing a text search. For example, `[articles] [abbreviations]` can really narrow a search (8 results) while `[sentence] [grammar]` doesn't (465 results). The oldest questions tagged [tag:reason-why] is about the phrase 'reason why', not asking for a reason why. If people don't know how to use it without a description, that's also an indicator it may be a bad tag.

Comment: @ColleenV - that's a good point. What's unclear to me is whether [reason-why] has the potential to be helpful when searching for dupes. (Re your last point, see my second 'paragraph'.)

Comment: In general, I think it is a bad idea to tag questions with the words they are asking about unless there is something about those words that make it difficult to search with a regular text search ([tag:to-for] or [tag:at-in] for example). ELL has a tag for "as" because learners have a lot of questions about it and it's impossible to effectively narrow a search down using it as text in the title or body.

Comment: In [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/180155), John Lawler states one reason why the phrase "the reason why" has grammar like no other phrase. As he says, there is only one "reason noun" that can precede "why" in this construct, and it's "reason". "the reason why" can be followed by a clause, or it can be a NP on its own (e.g. "Tell me the reason why."). Moreover, there are no similar phrases with that same grammar and different relatives; "the method how", "the place where", "the person who", "the purpose what for" don't work as NPs.

Comment: @RosieF What does that have to do with whether the tag is worthwhile?

Comment: @ColleenV Before you posted your comment, the word "worth" did not occur anywhere on this web page --- nobody had even raised the issue of anything being worth while. My point is that the grammar of the phrase "the reason why" is a fair topic for a question, and because it is specific to that phrase, `[reason-why]` is as good a name as any for the tag.

Comment: @RosieF It’s a fine topic for a question but it’s a terrible tag.

Comment: Since terminology is randomly used on this SE, in answers, comments, and tags, I see no reason to use the existing tag system for anything. Best to ignore it, since it's overblown and full of nonsense. Like making sense of political polls in partisan media.

Comment: Coming to this question from Hot Meta Posts with only a title and no context, I'd assume the tag was a meta-tag asking for a reason, and apparently, I was wrong (and also showed that it's ambiguous/prone to be misused)

Comment: It has veered off its original intent because there are no usage guidelines, obviously. It went from *reason-why* to a part thereof (just *reason* or *why*) to 'what is the reason for anything.' They were just grasping for tags, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Well, given that it's been two months since I've asked this question and it still hasn't been answered, it seems that nobody really knows what it's for. I really think there should be some consistency in the tagging, so here's my proposal for how they should be retagged:

- Remove it from questions that ask about the phrase "*reason why*". This is because there is probably a limited amount of questions that can be asked about that phrase, and searching for `title:"reason why"` is enough to find most of them.
- There seems to be a bit of a blur between this tag and the [etymology](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology) tag. I think that when retagging we can ask ourselves if the question is about *how* a phrase took on a meaning or about *why* it took on that meaning. The *how* questions can use the [etymology](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology) tag.
- Use it on questions that ask about explanations for linguistic phenomena.

How does that seem? I'm not steadfastly set on any of these parts of the proposal- this can be discussed, tweaked, or even overhauled as the community sees fit.

---

I got ahead of myself and retagged a few of the questions already; I've reverted those changes to allow for more discussion about the tag's usage.

Comment: I see the [tag:grammar] tag was left alone in this [post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119877/do-you-need-the-why-in-thats-the-reason-why), was it because it's more informative than the [tag:reason-why] tag? Where's the harm in tagging this common type of question? Is the reason because nobody answered, no one really cared. Fine, no one objected, so does that gives you the all clear? Your meta post hardly got an overwhelming call of support, the tepid response didn't give you carte blanche.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I rolled back my edits and re-framed this answer into a proposal rather than a plan. Sorry for violating etiquette.

Comment: Nobody knows what the tags are for and nobody can use them. It's like somebody took all the words they'd ever heard about English grammar and made a tag out of it; then somebody else, with no idea of what the original creator had in mind, wrote a description for it out of **their** experience, which was then edited and argued over by hundreds of other people. Naturally it's random and arbitrary.